# Why can't I get images from my S3 bucket when all public access blocked? 403 Forbidden But static files load fine

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

My Django website allows users to upload photos. When the s3 bucket is on public the media content loads fine on the site. However once i block all public access the content no longer loads and a 403 forbidden error is shown. In my code I have added the values needed to allow for authenticate requests. There are no bucket policy's or any CORS configurations. I have tried several different suggestions from blogs and tutorials but nothing seems to work.

I have a user which has programmatic access and set the secret variables in the heroku environment and still get 403 error.
I have tried hard setting the secret variables and still no success.

settings.py

```py
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

MEDIA_LOCATION = 'MediaStorage'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIA_LOCATION)
MEDIA_FILE_STORAGE = 'MediaStorage'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATIC_LOCATION)

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

storage_backends.py

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage
from django.conf import settings

class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.MEDIA_FILE_STORAGE
    file_overwrite = False
    custom_domain = False
```

All static files load fine but media files do not load at all. 
I expect the files to load when displaying them in the view web page. however i just get a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: Did you check if `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH` is set to True?

Comment: No where would i set that?

Comment: In your settings.py file. The default is True, so if it isn't included, it should be set to True, but you can add it just to be sure.

Comment: Have just set it but still no luck :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after many iterations it came down to a line of code missing in the storage_backends.py file missing the line
`custom_domain = False`

I have updated the original post to match the correct `storage_backends.py` file

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py your have set?

```
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
```

Look this example is an public project for my state in Brazil.

[Project](https://github.com/endersonmenezes/eufraim/blob/master/eufraim/settings.py)

Comment: Have you seen this by in the docs - 
`Warning`

`The default value of public-read is insecure and will be changing to None in a future release of django-storages. Please set this explicitly to public-read if that is the desired behavior.`

Comment: It's normal for public files, but it's a standard no longer recommended by Amazon. Amazon works with an ACL directive now, you can read more and configure your storages_backends more safely following the same standards, there are also some plugins that make this easier.

Comment: You can see [storage_backends.py example](https://github.com/endersonmenezes/eufraim/blob/master/eufraim/storage_backends.py), and my Private is another ACL, but the default is public. Sorry my english brother :)

Comment: okay i will make the changes in the backend see if it is successful. Thank you I will update you in several hours. Appreciate the help :)

Comment: Mark this are correct please, when you are satisfied ! <3
If your need any help contact me by email.

Comment: Did you try "reset" your bucket and re-upload archives?

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)` - This error is what appears for each image that is not able to load